# Unity2D tile sheet: colors change

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to build a game in unity, and I'm using a tile sheet as my frames for the enemies.
for some reason some of the pixels of each frame change their color when I'm trying to slice.

Any idea what causes the problem??

Answer (score 1):

compression of said files might interfere with the pixels colors, therefore, while browsing the image in unity, compression needs to be set to `None`